# Javascript Optimization for IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a Website which **only needs to support IE11**

It is a single page application, which has about **200 table rows** and each table row has **5 child rows**

There is a pulsing function that updates the table **as records come in**. Table rows are skipped over if no update comes in.

However, when receiving large updates (which should only occasionally happening), the application will hang as it slowly processes the javascript. I've tried to limit the javascript as much as possible, but still have a long running function.

I am a back end developer by nature, and was wondering if anyone had any tips to help support large table ajax updates for IE since IE so poorly handles JS.

Here is the function

```
function writeTableLines(tempRows){
    /* This Function takes care of updating the text and coloring of
    required dynamic fields. 
    All other values are not dynamically written.
    */
    for( i in tempRows){
   //i is the computer name
        tempValues = tempRows[i];
        // For Row
        selector = "[id='"+i+"']";

        // Network Name
        network_selector = "[id='"+i+"_network']";
        $(network_selector).text(tempValues['network']);

        if (tempValues['network_color']){
            $(network_selector).addClass(tempValues['network_color']);
            $(selector).find('.name').addClass(tempValues['network_color']);
        }else{
            $(network_selector).removeClass('warning');
             $(selector).find('.name').removeClass('warning');
        }

        // Boot Time
        boot_selector = "[id='"+i+"_boot']";
        $(boot_selector).text(tempValues['boot']);
        if (tempValues['boot_color']){
            $(boot_selector).addClass(tempValues['boot_color']);
            $(selector).find('.name').addClass(tempValues['boot_color'])
        }else{
            $(boot_selector).removeClass('issue');
            $(selector).find('.name').removeClass('issue');
        }

        // Last Checked In Timestamp
        check_in_selector = "[id='"+i+"_checked_in']";
        $(check_in_selector).text(tempValues['checked_in']);
        if (tempValues['service_unresponsive']){
            $(check_in_selector).addClass('redline');
            $(selector).find('.name').addClass('redline');
        }else{
            $(check_in_selector).removeClass('redline');
            $(selector).find('.name').removeClass('redline');
        }

        util_selector = $(selector).find('td.util').find('a');
        $(util_selector).text(tempValues['util'])
         if (tempValues['util_class']){
            $(util_selector).addClass(tempValues['util_class']);
        }else{
            $(util_selector).removeClass('redline warning');
        }

        workgroup_selector = $(selector).find('td.workgroup');

        if (($.trim(tempValues['workgroup'])) != $.trim($(workgroup_selector).text())){
            if ((tempValues['workgroup'] != selected) && (selected != 'All')){
                $(workgroup_selector).addClass('warning');
            }else{
                $(workgroup_selector).removeClass('warning');
            }
        }
        $(workgroup_selector).text(tempValues['workgroup'])
        toggle_links(i, tempRows[i]);
        $('#connectionGrid').trigger('updateAll', [false]);
    }
}
```

this function iterates over only received data.
For each row item that was received, update the text of the cell, and add coloring as necessary.

I'm thinking I might just be screwed since its IE, but am open to all suggestions and ideas.

Thanks for reading

Image of the rows - child rows only available when expanded, but still need updates

[image]

Comment: What are "child rows" of table rows?

Comment: It works, I want to see if I can optimize for better speed since IE has slow JS engine

Comment: @Teemu tablesorter child rows I will update with an image

Comment: There are a lot of possible paths for performance improvement (e.g. caching the results of selectors, or not using selectors in the first place). However, [codereview.se] may be a better place to ask this.

Comment: Thanks Frederic I will look over there

Comment: Putting your data into smaller more manageable chunks and going through them a chunk at a time with a short setTimeout delay between would remove the long running function problem and reduce the amount of time that the browser spends "locked up" while processing, but it's really just a bandaid until you optimize the code within the loop to run more efficiently (such as child rows not existing until expanded, proper pagination that doesn't involve simply hiding the dom, etc)

Comment: Frankly, I don't understand. I've developed a dozen SPA applications with Angularjs, and I didn't experience IE11 javascript bad performance. What I have experienced with IE11 is bad performance in large DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So In case anyone was wondering.

the last line `$('#connectionGrid').trigger('updateAll', [false]);` was being executed inside the loop.

As opposed to just once when the loop was finished.

Woops